# Javascript same domain information sharing

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have a website that holds one setting - a number that the user clicked.

I want the user to see this number and be able to change it at any time. Up until now I was using cookies to achieve this. But then I stumbled across an error : When user opens this address to my website :

```
http://ServerName/Pick
```

He sees a certain number. But when he opens this address :

```
http://ServerName.ServerDomain/Pick
```

He sees a diffirent number. And in the browser settings I see 2 cookies : one with the domain "ServerName" and one with the domain "ServerName.ServerDomain".

Is there any way to share the same cookie without relaying on wether the user specified a domain name? If not, is there a way to do this without cookies?

NOTE : I have full control over the client and server side (ASP.Net MVC)

Answer (score 0):

You can't share cookies for different domains, but you can use one domain as a primary domain that will issue a cookie and to read cookie from other domains you should redirect to that domain, read cookie and redirect back with a value in query string. Similar, like google redirects all Sign-In requests from google.com, google+, docs etc to account.gooogle.com or microsoft from MSN, Hotmail, etc to login.live.com and then back.